# Unable to download image if URL dont have www in android

Tags: android, url, download

I am trying to download an image from a URL. The problem I am facing is if the URL dont have www then I get error but if I add www it works fine. I am getting these URL from a webservice there are chances that some have www and some dont have and I am looking a solution to get rid of this issue.

If the URL is like that then no problem:
http://www.grindzmyreels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/minion.jpg

But in this case I get error:
http://grindzmyreels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/minion.jpg

Here is the code:

```
public void DownloadImage()
       {      

           HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpResponse httpResponse;
           Bitmap bmp = null;

           try{   

               httpResponse = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.grindzmyreels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/minion.jpg"));
              //int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
              HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

              if (entity != null)
              {
                  InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                  in.close();

                  String Path = bmp.toString();
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();                       
                  File mydir = context.getDir("MyFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
                  File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, Path ); //Getting a file within the dir.

                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);                   
                  out.close();


                   extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                   OutputStream outStream = null;
                   File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, Name+".PNG");                    
                   outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

                   filePath = file.toString();
                   outStream.flush();
                   outStream.close();  

              }                   
           } 
           catch (ClientProtocolException e)  
           {
               client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
               client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
               e.printStackTrace();
           }   

       }
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the URL to see if it contains www.
If it doesn't then you can add it into the string. Replacing `http://` with `http://www.` would be an easy way of doing this.

Here is an example

```
String URL = "http://grindzmyreels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/minion.jpg";

//if URL doesnt contain www. then add it after the http://
if(!URL.contains("www.")) URL.replace("http://", "http://www.");
```

Comment: What is the reason it doesn not work? what error message are you getting?
what is the exact link that is not working and I will find a solution that works for that? or did u try it using this URL I have already used?

Comment: What character do I had to add if there is a blank space in my URL?

Comment: a space would be `%20`
Or you could use
`String URL = Uri.parse("http://..")` which should do that all for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the URL from webservice then use check if the URL has www or not. If it doesn't then add it.

Comment: This may not even be an Android issue. Some sites are available at www.some-site.com and some-site.com - its all down to how the web server at the other end is configured. And don't forget about subdomains if you're going to try and decide if you should add 'www' or not.

Comment: @Phil not in my case. My webserver work with both but for some reason I am facing this issue from Android side.

Comment: @AliAbid Maybe your web server sends back a redirect when you hit the non-www URL (does the URL get re-written in the browser?); not all web servers will do this, important to be aware of if your code could be used against other webservers than your own.